# Can't get model binding to work in MVC2 

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmCreateUser", name = "frmCreateUser" })){%>
```

I am trying to send form data to controller where `Create` is method name and `user` is a method is a controller name.
syntax of the method

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
 public ActionResult Create(User UserToCreate)
 {
  //Controller action
 }
```

Syntax for the textbox

```
  <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new {id="UserName", size="30" })%>
```

Call goes fine on Create but User object give null why?

Comment: User is a class and UserToCreate is an object

Comment: i mean the properties...

Comment: I have mention one property which is UserName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TextBoxFor` helper method assigns a unique id to the input box so MVC can map the properties over when you post it to the server. Your overridding the id therefore your mapping will fail, change your textbox code to:

```
<% Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { size = 30 }) %>
```

Just to clarify, MVC maps properties using the `name` property of the input fields. However, I suspect that overridding the `id` property is effecting this. You can check the HTML output to clarify this, the name should look something like `user.username`.

**Edit**

Sandboxed your code into a small MVC3 project and it worked fine for me (even with setting the id!). Looking at the tags your using it would appear your using MVC2 instead of 3?

Comment: model binding should be based on "name" of form element, not id... no?

Comment: @ek_ny yes it does, however, I am pretty sure by default the name is set to whatever the id is set to (I may be wrong). I updated my question to clarify.

Comment: I just created a small sandbox app and got it working even with the ID being set in your original code! Either way you don't need to include set the `id` property of the field. I also just noticed your syntax looks like it's MVC2 not 3?

Comment: I have updated your question, problem is you tagged this as MVC3 and everyone has answered based on that. Hence why you might not understand a few of the answers (as they are referencing the `razor` syntax which was introduced in MVC3).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to assing id property. Be sure that Your view is strongly typed (by User)
like:

```
@model User
```

Comment: sorry for this question can you tell me with example where i have to do this?

Comment: On the top of Your view, In other case when You write: (model => model.UserName) MVC doesn't know that model is User and don't bind sending data with Your action. Look: ActionResult Create(User UserToCreate) - your action expects User and without strongly typed view You send NoOneKnowsWhat.

Comment: @KamilBędkowski See comments on my answer & also the updated question. OP is using MVC2 not MVC3.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a stab in the dark, but remove the id="UserName" part.

If your controller, is mapped to a specific class. Something like this should be fine.

```
@model  SomeSite.ViewModels.VM_User    

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.UserName, new { Class = "ui-corner-all FormElement ui-widget-content" })
```